# Is it possible to make an "entry point" server so to choose the best one?

Tags: networking

I have different servers, distributed across the network, they all deliver the same service.
Now, I'd like for the final user to have just an ip to know of: the ip of an "entry point" server. This server would then point the user to the best server, according to a policy I would specify.
Mind that I created an overlay network so the "entry" one would see every other server like local..this would make things easier..indeed I was thinking about a nat like mechanism but I don't know if there is any open source nat implementation with policies...what do you suggest me?
Every server is a linux one and I want open source solutions...

Comment: Are these servers all at the same site?

Comment: No they can be very far each other, but thanks to my overlay network they see themselves like they were on a local LAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution you're looking for is simply a network loadbalancer.

The [Linux Virtual Server](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) project is one such an OpenSource solution running on Linux.

If it is strictly a web service, many reverse proxy servers also have load balancing capabilities, i.e [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) for Apache.

Comment: Seems interesting but I can configure my own policies or, if not, what is the default one?My idea is to connect the user to the lowest lantency server,ie the one geographically more near.

Comment: The solution above is more a LAN solution as all traffic passes through the loadbalancer first, before reaching the "best" node. A typical solution to direct internet users to nearby servers are [GeoIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) DNS servers, or the [anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) routing protocol. In a corporate environment I expect that "Active Directory Sites and Services" allows you to configure a similar DNS based solution to direct your users to the local instance of your service.